# Google Geocode API IP restrictions

Tags: google-geocoder, ip-restrictions

When using IP restrictions for the Geocode API, what IP address should I put there? The IP address returned by a Google search of "What is my I.P."? Or the I.P address of the server where the application/website files are hosted?

I have a website under inMotion Hosting and I tried to put their i.p as in the restrictions, but that doesn't seem to work.

I don't think I have to put the internet I.P address of everybody who visits my website since I cannot know who will visit and where.

Please let me know, I'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you either have to pass ...

a) the server's IP, when geo-coding server-side (PHP API) or

b) the client's IP, when geo-coding client-side (JS API).

the server's IP should be known, for the client-side IP, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript).

in principle, it's always the IP of the party which actually requests data.